# How to make OR conditions while filtering Django Models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to make a query like this:

```
Mymodel.objects.filter(description__icontains='something' or title__icontains='something')
```

However using the `or` statement does not work. Putting a comma makes it an `and` statement. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrap the conditions in [**`Q`** objects [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q), and use the bitwise or operator (`|`) as an OR:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Mymodel.objects.filter(
    Q(description__icontains='something') |
    Q(title__icontains='something')
)
```